# Blinking Desktop LCD Screen

Tags: hardware-failure, lcd

I have Blinking Desktop LCD Screen I managed to find on the net that the problem is the backlight (LEDs). I disassembled the LCD. It look like this:[image]

[image]

[image]

Is their anything that I can do to fix my screen or reuse is for some other stuff like as a projector?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of backlights: LED and Cold cathode fluorescent lamps (CCFLs).
In case of CCFL they are dimed by a driver (called invertor). It is located in the bottom of the screen assembly as a separate PCB. You need to replace it.

IN case of the LED backlights driver is often integrated on the rear part of the screen, so you'll need to replace these circuits, but in many cases it's easier to replace the whole assembly.